# How to validate Required fields before the action onclick review.save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to validate Required fields before `onclick="review.save();"`

Is there any javascript to validate required fields before this action `onclick="review.save();`?

Here is my button code

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

This is the selection box code:

```
<label class="commentlabel required-entry" for="ordercomment-comment">
                <?php echo $survey_question; ?> <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="input-box required-entry">
<select class="validate-select" id="socialtype" name="socialtype1" title="<?php echo $survey_question ?>">
<option value=""><?php echo $this->__("- Select -");?></option>
<option value="Friend/Relative/Acquaintance"><?php echo $this->__("Friend/Relative/Acquaintance");?></option>
<option value="Google search"><?php echo $this->__("Google search");?></option>
<option value="Gumtree Advert"><?php echo $this->__("Gumtree Advert");?></option>
<option value="Facebook"><?php echo $this->__("Facebook");?></option>
<option value="Other"><?php echo $this->__("Other");?></option>
</select>
```

This is the opcheckout.js

```
var Review = Class.create();
Review.prototype = {
initialize: function(saveUrl, successUrl, agreementsForm){
    this.saveUrl = saveUrl;
    this.successUrl = successUrl;
    this.agreementsForm = agreementsForm;
    this.onSave = this.nextStep.bindAsEventListener(this);
    this.onComplete = this.resetLoadWaiting.bindAsEventListener(this);
},

save: function(){
    if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
    checkout.setLoadWaiting('review');
    var params = Form.serialize(payment.form);
    if (this.agreementsForm) {
        params += '&'+Form.serialize(this.agreementsForm);
    }
    params.save = true;
    var request = new Ajax.Request(
        this.saveUrl,
        {
            method:'post',
            parameters:params,
            onComplete: this.onComplete,
            onSuccess: this.onSave,
            onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
        }
    );
},

resetLoadWaiting: function(transport){
    checkout.setLoadWaiting(false, this.isSuccess);
},
```

Comment: For a detailed answer more code is needed. But i guess the validation part has to go into the `review.save()` function.

Comment: See this [**link**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/)

Comment: Or remove the `review.save()` from the button. Listen for a `form.submit` event. In the handler, do the validation and if valid, execute `review.save`

Answer (score 0):

You may create another function that validates field then execute the save function if successful. here's a minimal/sudo-code example

JS

```
var validation = {
   validate_review : function(){
      // do validation
      // ...
      if(success){
         review.save();
      }else{
         // show error message
      }
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="submit" onclick="validation.validate_review ();" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: I have less knowledge in JS.